# Can't Get Wordpress Post ID to Echo or Insert into Database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've got this code written that when a link is clicked is supposed to insert the current user's id, the current post's id, and the date into a database. The current user id & the current date get inserted into the database and echo's perfectly, but I can't get the current post's id to "echo" or get it to insert into the database. Here's the code I have so far:

```
global $post;
    global $wpdb;
    $wp_user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
    $activity_post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
    $activity_added = current_time('mysql', 1);

    echo "<h2>The Current User ID is: ". $wp_user_id . "</h2>";
    echo "<h2>The Current Activity ID is: ". $activity_post_id . "</h2>";
    echo "<h2>The Current Date / Time is: ". $activity_added . "</h2>";

    $wpdb->insert(
        'wp_growwellactivities',
        array(
            'wp_user_id' => $wp_user_id,
            'activity_post_id' => $activity_post_id,
            'date_added' => $activity_added
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to access wp_query without using the global.

Change your globals to:

```
global $post, $wp_query, $wpdb;
```

Or use this instead:

```
$activity_post_id = $post->ID;
```

Comment: I'm still not getting a result returned. Does it matter that I'm calling this from a plugin? It's weird because I can echo out the other two variables but the one related to a wordpress post won't echo or be inserted into the db

Comment: If you're calling it too early you aren't going to get a result. Make sure this at some point after the posts_selection hook. Before then no post has been queried so there is no post data.

Comment: That worked. I changed the action from init to wp_head. I appreciate your help

Comment: I'd suggest using the 'wp' action but it should be fine. Pleased I could help.